How to classify a structured data relationship when the comparators exhibit multiple relationships
I'm trying to pin down how to understand what defines whether two items in a relationship have a certain type of relationship.
For example, in the following table, Author CAN have a many-to-one relationship with Book. But it doesn't always, and in most instances does not. Would I say Author has a one-to-one or a one-to-many relationship with Book?
Relatedly, is a relationship type determined by which relationship type within scope is most common, or is it determined solely by whether a specific relationship type CAN occur?


You would consider author to book to generally be one to many.  But really, it should be many to many, given that a book may have many authors, and an author many books.

The relationship type defines the relationship between entities not the specific relationship between instances of entities. So if a relationship between entities is m:m then that is its type, the fact that a specific instance might be 1:m is irrelevant
